Prevent cursor from jumping with locked cells
In an invoice form, only the input fields are selectable, the rest of the table is locked. The user can only change two items per invoice line: Duration and Description of activity. The consecutive number, the hourly rate etc. are predefined and the corresponding cells cannot be selected. If the user enters the activity description for the last activity to be invoiced (i.e. if he is in the last selectable cell of the sheet) and then presses Enter, the cursor jumps out of the screen to a (released) cell containing the hourly rate. That is ugly. How can I make it so that only in the last input cell (the column always remains the same, but the row changes depending on the number of invoice items) pressing the Enter key has no effect?
My code currently looks like this:
Sub EnterKey()
    If Not Intersect(Selection, Cells(Cells(2, 13).Value, 5)) Is Nothing Then
        KeyCode = 0
    End If
End Sub

The routine is called by an entry in the Workbook_Open:
Application.OnKey ‘~’, ‘EnterKey’
The effect, however, is that the cursor does not move forward at all, regardless of which (released) cell it is in.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance and best regards
Stefano
Implementing this subs I expected that with pressing enter in the last unlocked cell cursor does not jump to the next unlocked cell.

Does M2 contain the last cell's row i.e. if M2 contains 10, when E10 is changed, the cursor should remain there?
